# how to delete localDB databases in SSMS in one shot

Tags: ssms, localdb

This is related to a previous question [How to delete (localdb) database if the file is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411005/how-to-delete-localdb-database-if-the-file-is-gone/22433866#22433866).
I use SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to edit local databases created within Visual Studio by connecting to (LocalDB)\v11.0 as server. After a while, I would see all the databases that I ever connected to, most of which are gone. I can delete/detach these long-gone databases one by one manually. But would appreciate a way to delete all of them in one shot. ANyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Object Explorer Details pane as follows:

1. Open Object Explorer Details (View menu)
2. Click on the Databases node of the Object Explorer
3. In Object Explorer Details, multi-select the databases you want to delete
   by depressing the Ctrl or Shift key while selecting them
4. Right click and select Delete

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple batch file to delete an SQL local db. It uses trusted connection. But you can add credentials with `-U Username` `-P Password` parameters. Further info [check out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)!

[image]

```
@echo off
set /p DbName=Enter local db name:
echo.
sqlcmd -e -S "(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -d "master" -Q "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'%DbName%'; USE [master]; DROP DATABASE [%DbName%];"
echo Finished!
pause > nul
```